# Extract numbers from number records and pass null to alphanumeric in Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, numbers, case, non-alphanumeric

I have a test table in Postgresql. It has a field value_exist which is a string but it has alphanumeric values in it and some special characters in the data. I want to ignore the characters [/alpha/?/$/encoding/.] in it and check if the record has only numbers. If its only numbers then we need only numbers else for alphanumeric we need null. Refer the below example :

[image]
I tried the below code but it doesn't give me the desired output :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN value_exist ~ '^([$?\\*+-][0-9]|[0-9][$?\\*+-]|[0-9][0-9])$'
                THEN REGEXP_REPLACE(value_exist, '[$?\\*+-]', '', 'g')
                ELSE NULL END value_new
    FROM test_table
```

Comment: Need only exact numerics i.e. 0-9 from number records, rest all (special characters/alphanumeric) passed as null.

Comment: Please clarify the question. What is `[/alpha/?/$/encoding/.]`? Integer numbers or floating point numbers? With or without sign? Do In understand correctly that the result can only be a number or `NULL`?

Comment: alpha - alphabets , $ - special characters , encoding could be any characters that are in the table. I tried the below,it works for alphanumeric: SELECT (case when 'kk9' ~ '([ a-z A-Z ])' then null
else 77 end) K. But I want to check for "$99$" - This should give me null but it is not giving me null. So, for $ it is not able to handle it.

Comment: Well, answer my questions, and I can answer yours.

Comment: 1) What is [/alpha/?/$/encoding/.]? alpha - alphabets,?,$ and any encoding/special characters should be passed as null.
 2) Integer numbers or floating point numbers? Integer numbers 
3) With or without sign? It can have - + signs as well , this should be passed as null
4) Do In understand correctly that the result can only be a number or NULL? The result should contain ONLY numbers for only number values and null for other values.

Comment: I tried using the below and it seems that it works, i am not sure if I can use the below or if this is correct or any other better way ? : SELECT (case when '9955?' ~ '([ a-z A-Z $ - ?])' then null
else 77 end) K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this and this works.. It takes only numbers and if we get other than numbers including numbers then it passes it as null .

```
select case when 'H44$'~'^[0-9]*$' then 88
else null end ---- Result -> null

 select case when '44'~'^[0-9]*$' then 88
 else null end   ---- Result -> 44
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT nullif(
          regexp_replace(
             value_exist,
             E'^.*[^\\d].*$',
             'x'),
          'x')
FROM test_table;
```

Comment: SELECT nullif(
          regexp_replace(
             '44',
             '^.*[^\d].*$',
             ''),
          'g');
FROM test_table;    --> This gives me null

Comment: SELECT nullif(
          regexp_replace(
             '44',
             '^.*[^\d].*$',
             'x'),
          'x');   -- This gives me null

Comment: Maybe you have a very old PostgreSQL version. I have modified the answer to use extended string syntax, that should work everywhere. Second thought: if you embed this string in a programming language like Java or C, you'd have to double backslashes.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.. Yups i have a old PostgreSQL version.. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks are best expressed with upvote and/or accepting as correct answer. I'm pleased I could help.